# Clear timeout of a functions inside global function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cleartimeout

I have set a function that loads on document ready with name myFunction. There are 5 functions inside it with different timeouts. I want to clearTimeout of 3rd and 4th functions on clicking a button inside my html code with id #btn . Here is my code

```
<doctype! HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>
My Page
</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js">
<script src="myScript.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(myFunction);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">
</body>
</html>
```

myScript.js is below

```
function myFunction(){
setTimeout(function function1(){
 // do stuffs
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function function2(){
 // do stuffs
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function function3(){
 // do stuffs
}, 15000);
setTimeout(function function4(){
 // do stuffs
}, 20000);
setTimeout(function function5(){
 // do stuffs
}, 25000);
}
```

Comment: where is the rest of code ??? where is the HTML..... dont keep us guessing

Comment: sorry editing question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear a timeout, you must assign it to a variable which holds the reference. Here is an example:

```
var t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;

function myFunction(){
    t1 = setTimeout(function function1(){
     // do stuffs
    }, 5000);
    t2 = setTimeout(function function2(){
     // do stuffs
    }, 10000);
    t3 = setTimeout(function function3(){
     // do stuffs
    }, 15000);
    t4 = setTimeout(function function4(){
     // do stuffs
    }, 20000);
    t5 = setTimeout(function function5(){
     // do stuffs
    }, 25000);
}

function myClearFunction(){
    clearTimeout(t3);
    clearTimeout(t4);
}
```

Call `myClearFunction()` from your button to clear the third and forth timers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearTimeout` for this. Here's a functional demo:

```js
var timer1 = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timer1');
}, 5000);
var timer2 = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timer2');
}, 10000);
var timer3 = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timer3');
}, 15000);
var timer4 = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timer4');
}, 20000);
var timer5 = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('timer5');
}, 25000);

document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer3);
  clearTimeout(timer4);
});
```

```html
<button id="x">Stop Timer 3 and 4</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

SetTimeout returns a value, save that for timer 3 and 4 and then on click button click cancel those. Make sure to check if the values for 3-4 are defined before calling clear on them.

```
Return Value:   A Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearTimeout() method to cancel the timer
```

from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp